# Size absolute child to parent width

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position, css-tables

I'm trying to make a child popup be the same size of it's parent but can't seem to do so. This is what I currently have (It's definitely not working with a fixed width).

html

```
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li class="active current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li> <!-- this parent -->
    <a href="#">Items</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: block;"> <!-- this child -->
      <a id="9" href="#">items 1</a>
      <a id="10" href="#">item 50</a>
      <a id="11" href="#">item long name</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.navmenu .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

    width: 150px;
}

.navmenu .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
   padding: 6px 0px;
}
```

I've tried changing the width to

```
width: 100%;
```

and

```
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
```

But then the element takes the size of the window and not the parent. Here is fiddle of what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/aywmn3zt/10/.

Comment: By **parent** do you mean the `li` ?

Comment: yes the `<li>` with the `<div>`

Comment: did you add position relative to the parent? - http://jsfiddle.net/aywmn3zt/12/

Comment: The parent has to have `position:relative`...I'd start there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the parent `li` and then `width: 100%` to the dropdown and it works fine.

```
.navmenu li{
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: table
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%
}

ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  border: 0 none;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 15px
}

ul {
  min-height: 29px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0054ae;
  color: #fff
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #004d9f;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap
}

ul li a:focus,
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #006bdc;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none
}

ul .active a,
ul .active a:hover,
ul .active a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #004185;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  font-weight: bold
}

.navmenu {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  list-style: none
}

.navmenu li a {
  display: block
}

.navmenu li a:hover,
.navmenu li a:focus {
  background-color: #ebf3f4
}

.navmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0
}

.navmenu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navmenu li{
  position: relative;
}

.navmenu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li class="active current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Items</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: block;">
      <a id="9" href="#">items 1</a>
      <a id="10" href="#">item 50</a>
      <a id="11" href="#">item long name</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks that worked. I do have another problem now when I try it in my complete code, where a scroll bar appear instead http://jsfiddle.net/aywmn3zt/14/

Comment: give `overflow: hidden` to `navbar`

Comment: removing the overflow `auto` and `hidden` in the different locations fixed it, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Set parent `li` to `position:relative`. The position absolute child is positioned with respect to its nearest position relative parent.

```css
ul {
  display: table
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  border: 0 none;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 15px
}

ul {
  min-height: 29px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0054ae;
  color: #fff
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #004d9f;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap
}

ul li a:focus,
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #006bdc;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none
}

ul .active a,
ul .active a:hover,
ul .active a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #004185;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  font-weight: bold
}

.navmenu {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  list-style: none
}

.navmenu li a {
  display: block
}

.navmenu li a:hover,
.navmenu li a:focus {
  background-color: #ebf3f4
}

.navmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0
}

.navmenu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  
  /*left: 0px;
  right: 0px;*/
}

.navmenu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li class="active current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Items</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: block;">
      <a id="9" href="#">items 1</a>
      <a id="10" href="#">item 50</a>
      <a id="11" href="#">item long name</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to `li` and `width: 100% to`.navmenu .dropdown-content`.

**Note**: Your code have repetitive styles, check and make it tidier.

**Here is a working example:**

```css
ul.navmenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  min-height: 29px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0054ae;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
ul.navmenu li {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
ul.navmenu li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #004d9f;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.navmenu li a:focus,
ul.navmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #006bdc;
}
ul.navmenu li.active a {
  background-color: #004185;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
ul.navmenu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
}
ul.navmenu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navmenu">
  <li class="active current"><a href="/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Items</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="display: block;">
      <a id="9" href="#">items 1</a>
      <a id="10" href="#">item 50</a>
      <a id="11" href="#">item long name</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aywmn3zt/13/)

css

```
ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  position:relative /* make it relative so that absolute positioned children of it will be placed wrt li */
}

.navmenu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /*width: 150px;*/
  left: 0px; /* make it to left */
  right: 0px; /* to right this will help to take the width of its parent */
}
```